# "Must declare the table variable "@name"" in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure which returns the error:

> Must declare the table variable "@PropIDs".

But it is followed with the message:

> (123 row(s) affected)

The error appears when I execute it with

```
EXEC [dbo].[GetNeededProperties] '1,3,5,7,2,12', '06/28/2013', 'TT'
```

But works fine when

```
EXEC [dbo].[GetNeededProperties] NULL, '06/28/2013', 'TT'
```

Can any one help me with that?
The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNeededProperties]
@NotNeededWPRNs nvarchar(max), --string like '1,2,3,4,5'
@LastSynch datetime,
@TechCode varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PropIDs TABLE
(ID bigint)
Declare @ProductsSQL nvarchar(max);
SET @ProductsSQL = 'Insert into @PropIDs (ID) 
SELECT [WPRN] FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE(WPRN in (' + @NotNeededWPRNs + '))'
exec sp_executesql @ProductsSQL

SELECT  p.WPRN AS ID,
p.Address  AS Address,
p.Address AS Street
  FROM [dbo].[Properties] AS p
WHERE 
   p.WPRN NOT IN( SELECT ID FROM @PropIDs)
```

---

I've found kind of solution when declaring table like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#PropIDs', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #PropIDs

CREATE  TABLE  #PropIDs
```

But when execute the procedure from C# (linq sql) it returns an error

Comment: Show how are you invoking SP from c#?

Comment: When you create a temp table with the # the way you have its actually stored in sql server and needs to be deleted once you are done using it, the temp table you have created is a scalar variable and is propbably inaccessible at that point

Comment: Small thing: when you declare your dynamic SQL variable as nvarchar, you should use `N` to declare string literals: `N'Insert into...` or it won't use Unicode

Comment: `'1,3,5,7,2,12'` is a **single string** that you're passing to your stored procedure, but the `IN (....)` operator expects **a list of values** - not a single string! You should be using a table-valued parameter for your ID's which allows you to pass in multiple values from the caller in a proper, well-defined way, and then you don't need to resort to dynamic SQL, either! TVP's are available in SQL Server **2008** and newer.

Comment: As an aside, unless you are working in the TempDB you will need to prefix your temp table with `TempDB..` in this line `IF OBJECT_ID('#PropIDs', 'U') IS NOT NULL`, i.e. `IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#PropIDs', 'U') IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use table variable in a dynamic sql statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626292/how-to-use-table-variable-in-a-dynamic-sql-statement)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that you're mixing up dynamic SQL with non-dynamic SQL.

Firstly - the reason it works when you put NULL into @NotNeededWPRNs is because when that variable is NULL, your @ProductsSQL becomes NULL.

WHat you need to do is either make your @PropsIDs table a non-table variable and either a temporary table or a physical table. 
OR
you need to wrap everything in dynamic SQL and execute it.

So the easy way is to do something like this:

```
Declare @ProductsSQL nvarchar(max);
    SET @ProductsSQL = '
    DECLARE @PropIDs TABLE
    (ID bigint)
    Insert into @PropIDs (ID) 
    SELECT [WPRN] FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE(WPRN in (' + @NotNeededWPRNs + '))

    SELECT  p.WPRN AS ID,
    p.Address  AS Address,
    p.Address AS Street
      FROM [dbo].[Properties] AS p
    WHERE 
       p.WPRN NOT IN( SELECT ID FROM @PropIDs)
    '
```

and execute that.
OR as mentioned - change @ProdIDs to a temporary table. (The route you're approaching in the CREATE #ProdIds, but then you need to use #ProdIDs instead of @ProdIDs everywhere in the sproc).

Comment: thanks, it works now with temp table '#ProdIDs' . I haven't try the first solution but i will do that because I'm not sure how it will work with linq

Answer (score 7):

Change you code to :

```
Declare @ProductsSQL nvarchar(max);
SET @ProductsSQL = 'DECLARE @PropIDs TABLE
(ID bigint);
Insert into @PropIDs (ID) 
SELECT [WPRN] FROM [dbo].[Properties] WHERE(WPRN in (' + @NotNeededWPRNs + '))'
exec sp_executesql @ProductsSQL
```

Table variable declared outside the dynamic SQL will not be available to the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Correct. I was only trying to point out what the problem was. Not rewriting the code for him :)

Comment: Thanks - now it works when i execute it using `EXEC`. Nut I'm getting an exception when executing it from C# now `Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'`. Do you have any idea what might cause that?

Comment: never mind -the error was caused by empty (but not null) string parameter: ''

Answer (score 7):

The reason you get this error is that the scope of table variables is limited to a single batch, since `sp_executesql` runs in its own batch, it has no knowledge that you have declared it in another batch.

It works when you `@NotNeededWPRNs` is `NULL` because concatenating `NULL` yields `NULL` (unless otherwise set), so you are just executing:

```
exec sp_executesql null;
```

I would also say, if you are using SQL Server 2008 or later **please** consider using [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a delimited list of strings. This is much safer and more efficient, and validates the input, if I were to pass `1); DROP TABLE dbo.Prioperties; --` as `@NotNeededWPRNs`, you could find yourself without a properties table.

First you would need to create the type (I tend to use a generic name for reusability):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntegerList TABLE (Value INT);
```

Then you can add it to your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNeededProperties]
    @NotNeededWPRNs dbo.IntegerList READONLY,
    @LastSynch DATETIME,
    @TechCode VARCHAR(5)
    AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT  p.WPRN AS ID,
            p.Address  AS Address,
            p.Address AS Street
     FROM   [dbo].[Properties] AS p
    WHERE   p.WPRN NOT IN (SELECT Value FROM @NotNeededWPRNs)
```

On an unrelated note, you should avoid using culture sensitive date formats where possible, `06/28/2013` is clearly supposed to be 28th June in this case, but what about `06/07/2013`, without setting `DATEFORMAT`, or the language how do you know if this will be read as 6th July or 7th June? The best format to use is `yyyyMMdd`, it is never ambiguous, even the ISO standard format yyyy-MM-dd can be interpreted as `yyyy-dd-MM` in some settings.

Comment: thanks for all suggestions - now I've managed to make it work but I will get back to this to make some improvements

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using dynamic sql by creating a sql function that use a CTE (I found the code below many years ago on sqlservercentral - Amit Gaur) :

Change the body of your procs with something like this :

```
SELECT  p.WPRN AS ID,
p.Address  AS Address,
p.Address AS Street
  FROM [dbo].[Properties] AS p
WHERE 
   p.WPRN NOT IN ( SELECT item FROM dbo.strToTable(@NotNeededWPRNs, ','))
```

Below the sql code that transforms a string into a table :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[strToTable] 
(
    @array varchar(max),
    @del char(1)
)
RETURNS 
@listTable TABLE 
(
    item int
)
AS
BEGIN

    WITH rep (item,list) AS
    (
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@array,1,CHARINDEX(@del,@array,1) - 1) as item,
        SUBSTRING(@array,CHARINDEX(@del,@array,1) + 1, LEN(@array)) + @del list

        UNION ALL

        SELECT SUBSTRING(list,1,CHARINDEX(@del,list,1) - 1) as item,
        SUBSTRING(list,CHARINDEX(@del,list,1) + 1, LEN(list)) list
        FROM rep
        WHERE LEN(rep.list) > 0
    )
    INSERT INTO @listTable
    SELECT item FROM rep

    RETURN 
END
```