# SQL Update Trigger for writing entire row to another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I posted a question yesterday and this is related. I have a table called People_Master

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People_Master](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(900001,1) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[uac] [int] NULL,
[department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_People_Master] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
```

And I have created another table called People_Delta

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People_Delta](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[uac] [int] NULL,
[Department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[change_type] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Notice that I have one additional column in People_Delta called "**change_type**"

Now I'm trying to write an update trigger for People_Master so that when an update happens on it, it should write that entire row to People_Delta and set the change_type to "Modify".

Here is the trigger I have written (I'm not good at SQL. Lol!)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Update] 
   ON  [dbo].[People_Master]
   AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @RowCount int
    Declare @ID int

    --Create a temp table to hold the inserted data.
    Declare @TempTable As Table
    (
        [ID] [int],
        [Email] [nvarchar](50) ,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](50),
        [uac] [int] ,
        [department] [nvarchar](50)     
    )

    Insert Into @TempTable (ID,Email,FirstName,uac,department)
    select 
        ID,
        Email,
        FirstName,
        uac,
        department
    from
        inserted    


    select @ID = ID from inserted

    --check if the row for this ID doesnt exist already.
    Select @RowCount=COUNT(*) from People_Delta where People_Delta.ID = @ID and People_Delta.change_type = 'Modify';

    if(@RowCount = 0)
    Begin
        Insert into People_Delta (ID,Email,FirstName,uac,Department,change_type)
        values (@TempTable.ID,@TempTable.Email,@TempTable.FirstName,@TempTable.uac,@TempTable.department,'Modify');
    END

END

GO
```

However, when I execute this trigger, I get the following error:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_Update, Line 50
Must declare the scalar variable "@TempTable".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_Update, Line 50
Must declare the scalar variable "@TempTable".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_Update, Line 50
Must declare the scalar variable "@TempTable".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_Update, Line 50
Must declare the scalar variable "@TempTable".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_Update, Line 50
Must declare the scalar variable "@TempTable".
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please help!
GT.

Comment: Also perhaps based on my requirements, is there a better way to accomplish this? Seems to me the problem with above is that if I lets say have to change my table design, like add a new column, I will have to change my trigger definition to include that column in the update for People_Delta too.

Comment: If you want to add more to your question, you can [edit] it. You shouldn't ever need to add a comment directly on your own questions (or answers)

Comment: maybe this might help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265023/must-declare-the-table-variable-name-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this trigger.

Changed this insert query

```
 Insert into People_Delta (ID,Email,FirstName,uac,Department,change_type)
        values (@TempTable.ID,@TempTable.Email,@TempTable.FirstName,@TempTable.uac,
                @TempTable.department,'Modify');
```

to

```
Insert into People_Delta (ID,Email,FirstName,uac,Department,change_type)
        select  ID, Email,FirstName, uac, department, 'Modify'    from
        inserted
```

**Updated Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Update] 
   ON  [dbo].[People_Master]
   AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare @ID int

    select @ID = ID from inserted

    If NOT EXISTS(Select People_Delta.ID from People_Delta where People_Delta.ID = @ID 
                       and People_Delta.change_type = 'Modify')
    BEGIN
         Insert into People_Delta (ID,Email,FirstName,uac,Department,change_type)
          select  ID, Email,FirstName, uac, department, 'Modify'    from
          inserted  
    END
END
```

Comment: Why are you use @TempTable table in trigger??

Comment: @Mukesh Kalgude: Not needed. I removed that.

Comment: even no need of 'select *' instead use always 'Select 1' when need to check exists or not exists. why should we force to fetch all the columns.

Comment: `select @ID = ID from inserted` is still wrong since `inserted` is a table with possibly many rows