# “Must declare the table variable” Error with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting following errors when I use a table variable inside a CTE in SQL Server 2005. When I use a physical table, it works fine.

> Must declare the table variable "@Employee".
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Code:

```
DECLARE @Emploee TABLE (EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(50), Dept VARCHAR(5), Manager INT)

INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (1, 'A', NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (2, 'B', 'D100',NULL)

;WITH EmployeeManagers AS 
(
  SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, 1 AS Level
       , e.Manager, e.EmpID CurrLevelEmpID, Cast(Null as VarChar(5)) Dept
  FROM   @Employee AS e
  WHERE  e.Manager IS NOT NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT em.EmpId, em.EmpName, Level + 1 AS Level
       , e.Manager, e.EmpID CurrLevelEmpID, e.Dept Dept
  FROM   EmployeeManagers em
         INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.EmpId = em.Manager
)
SELECT * FROM EmployeeManagers
```

How can we fix this error?

**REFERENCE**

[How to use table variable in a dynamic sql statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626292/how-to-use-table-variable-in-a-dynamic-sql-statement)

Comment: You've misspelled the @Emploee table at the top - try adding the missing y and rerunning

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: This was due to a typo from my side in table creation. I would like this to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Emploee TABLE (EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(50), Dept VARCHAR(5), Manager INT)

INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (1, 'A', NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (2, 'B', 'D100',NULL)

;WITH EmployeeManagers AS 
(
  SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, 1 AS Level
       , e.Manager, e.EmpID CurrLevelEmpID, Cast(Null as VarChar(5)) Dept
  FROM   @Emploee AS e         --<-- Wrong Spellings here
  WHERE  e.Manager IS NOT NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT em.EmpId, em.EmpName, Level + 1 AS Level
       , e.Manager, e.EmpID CurrLevelEmpID, e.Dept Dept
  FROM   EmployeeManagers em
         INNER JOIN @Emploee  e ON e.EmpId = em.Manager  --<-- Mising @ sign here
)
SELECT * FROM EmployeeManagers
```

Comment: Also both of your employees has no manager to them, so this query will not return any data with these two records.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
DECLARE @Emploee TABLE (EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(50), Dept VARCHAR(5), Manager INT)

INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (1, 'A', NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO @Emploee VALUES (2, 'B', 'D100',NULL)
```

Should be @Employee